# No space between characters under \texttt{} command

Tags: fonts, spacing, code

To provide special font to my code, I'm using the structure:

```
\texttt{$ a is = b OR (c \& d)$}
```

The obtained output is:

> ais=bOR(c&d)

all the spaces are neglected. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Whatever you put within `$` is math mode, so TeX treats your `$ a is …` as the product of the variables `a`, `i`, `s`, etc. Why did you put a `$` there / where did you learn to do that? (I'm sure the kind of “problem” you're having has been asked and answered many times on this site, but I can't find the exact duplicate right now…)

Comment: The $ has been used because variables a, b ,c etc have subscripts associated with them, such as $a_1$ etc.

The final aim  is to have the code printed  as a 'code' , rather than the regular font used for rest of the text.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `\mathtt{}` to be used in math mode. Or `\texttt{}` to be used in text mode. But, please, don't mix text with symbol. Consider writing `$a$ is equal to $b$ OR $(c\&d)$`.

Comment: I suspect that  what the OP really wants is `\texttt{a = b OR (c \& d)}`. I'm not certain about it, though

Comment: Yes Mico, that is right. thank you Sigur ! 
If you have any specific font for writing codes in mind, please do share.

Comment: @ChintanBhomia, so what you need is `verbatim` environment for longer codes. Or `\texttt{}` or `\verb`.